# Convert SQL request onto Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to use Eloquent in a CRUD. This CRUD uses several datas from 4 tables.

**admins :**

```
Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('surname');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

**langs :**

```
Schema::create('langs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('isocode', 10)->nullable();
    $table->string('name', 80)->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**lang_sector:**

```
Schema::create('lang_sector', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('lang_id')->index('FK_LANGS');
    $table->integer('sector_id')->index('FK_SECTORS');
    $table->integer('admin_id')->index('FK_ADMINS');
    $table->string('name', 80)->nullable();
    $table->string('shortname', 40)->nullable();
    $table->text('description', 65535)->nullable();
    $table->primary(['lang_id','sector_id']);
});
```

**sectors:**

```
Schema::create('sectors', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

And setup relations in the model :

- A sector belong to one Admin
- An Admin has many Sector
- Sector belong to many language
- Lang belong to many Sector

**in sector model :**

```
public function langs(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lang')->withPivot('name','shortname','description');
}
public function Admin(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Admin');
}
```

**In lang model :**

```
public function sectors(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sector')->withPivot('name','shortname','description');
}
```

**In Admin model**

```
public function sectors(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Sector');
}
```

The information I'd like to display can be represented with this SQL request (updated version) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  sectors.id,
  lang_sector.sector_id,
  lang_sector.lang_id,
  lang_sector.admin_id,
  langs.name,
  lang_sector.name,
  lang_sector.shortname,
  admins.name,
  admins.surname,
  sectors.created_at,
  sectors.updated_at
FROM lang_sector
INNER JOIN
  langs ON langs.id = lang_sector.lang_id
INNER JOIN
  sectors ON sectors.id = lang_sectors.sector_id
INNER JOIN
  admins ON admins.id = lang_sector.admin_id
ORDER BY lang_sector.sector_id;
```

My questions are :

- how to "translate" it in Eloquent and not in RAW SQL ...( $langs = Lang::latest('updated_at')->get();...)
- My other issue is that I want to have the logged admin as value...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't see an `admin_id` column in your `sectors` table?

Comment: Also, in your SQL query you're joining the `sectors` table, but not actually using that table for anything?

Comment: I forgot to update the SQL ...

Comment: I modified it ... I'm getting a little bit tired tonight :)) thanks for your comment

Comment: Seeing as how your SQL query doesn't confirm to a single entity, I'd suggest using the DB query builder instead of querying an entity. Alternatively, you could query an entity and eager load the relations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to fubar I began to look DB Query builder ...

```
$sector = DB::table('lang_sector')
    ->join('langs', 'langs.id', '=', 'lang_sector.lang_id')
    ->join('sectors', 'sectors.id', '=', 'lang_sector.sector_id')
    ->join('admins', 'admins.id', '=', 'lang_sector.admin_id')
    ->select('sectors.id', 'lang_sector.sector_id', 'lang_sector.lang_id',  'lang_sector.admin_id', 'langs.name', 'lang_sector.name', 'lang_sector.shortname',  'admins.name', 'admins.surname', 'sectors.created_at', 'sectors.updated_at')
    ->distinct()
    ->orderByRaw('lang_sector.sector_id')
    ->get();

    return view('admin.sectors',compact('sector'));
```

I check in the  view :

```
{{ dd('sector') }}
```

As a result I obtain a collection ... Unfortunatelly I have an issue when I want to display the results :

The request is correct but my collection don't display all required information :

```
Collection {#480 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    0 => {#380 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"sector_id": 1
      +"lang_id": 1
      +"admin_id": 1
      +"name": "Vera"
      +"shortname": "TIC"
      +"surname": "David"
      +"created_at": null
      +"updated_at": null
    }
    1 => {#487 ▶}
    2 => {#485 ▶}
    3 => {#386 ▶}
    4 => {#383 ▶}
    5 => {#488 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I will rename the different fields of the database in order to make each one unique ...